# How to put label on bar plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I am beginner in r and I faced to two problems here. I am grateful if anyone can help me.

1. What am I doing wrong that my code does not show me the right distribution in my bar plot? (I am trying to show the survived rate based on sex and class)
2. How can I show the value of each label on top of each bar?

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot)

ds <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
color_survived = "#FFA500"
color_dead = "#0000FF"

ds$Sex <- as.factor(ds$Sex)

ds$Survived <- as.factor(ds$Survived)

categorical.ds <- ds  %>%
  select(Sex,
         Class,
         Survived) %>%
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", -Survived)

categorical.ds %>% 
  ggplot(ds ,aes(value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x        = value, 
               fill     = Survived), 
               alpha    = .2, 
               position = "dodge", 
               color    = "black",
               width    = .7) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "") +
  theme(
    axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free", nrow = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(color_survived, color_dead), name   = "Survived", labels = c("Survived", "Dead"))
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: That's because the original dataset is already aggregated where the `Freq` column (which you dropped) gives the number of survivors by sex and class. Because of this there is an equal number of "observations" per class and sex and therefore all of your bars have the same height or count. I would suggest to keep the `Freq`column and make use of `geom_col`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is something, hope it helps!

long story short:

- I think you did something too complex if what you want is just survivors rate, no need to use `gather` (if you really want to, `pivot_longer` is more recommended). I used `group_by` and `summarize` instead, which is what you need for aggregations.
- Since both graphics haven't the same x, it's simpler to make 2 graphics, one for class, the other for sex. Then combine them with +, having `patchwork` loaded.
- beware, `geom_col` is what you want, `geom_bar` is plotting counts
- Regarding your label issue, just use `geom_text`

welcome in R commmunity!

```
##we need the tidyverse package for data manipulation and ggplot
library(tidyverse)
##since we'll make 2 different graphs, patchwork will allow us to combine them
library(patchwork)

#data reproduction
ds <- data.frame(Sex = sample(c("male", "female"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                 Survived = sample(c("survived", "dead"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                 Class = sample(c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "crew"), size = 100, replace = TRUE))

#I start with classes : group_by allows us to compute the rate of each group
#summarize uses these group to compute the rate : number of survivors / number in the group (and not NA)
class.ds <-  ds  %>%
  select(Class, Survived) %>%
    group_by(Class) %>%
    summarize(surv_rate = sum(Survived == "survived") / sum(!is.na(Survived)))

#we do the same for the sex
sex.ds <- ds  %>%
  select(Sex, Survived) %>%
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  summarize(surv_rate = sum(Survived == "survived") / sum(!is.na(Survived)))

#now the plots : class is our x axis, the rate is the y axis.
#geom_col is used for the bars, geom_text is for the labels
#of course, you can then add color etc, here I keep it simple
class.plot <- class.ds %>% ggplot(aes(Class, surv_rate)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(surv_rate, 2)), nudge_y = 0.02)

#same thing for the sex
sex.plot <- sex.ds %>% ggplot(aes(Sex, surv_rate)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(surv_rate, 2)), nudge_y = 0.02)

#now we just need to group the graphs with patchowork
class.plot + sex.plot
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. What is "class" in class.plot? I cannot run the code.

Comment: Hi, in "class.plot", "class" is nothing, just a name. When I create the plot, I call it "class.plot", using the "<-" to do so. I could have call it "plot1" or anything. Which line of the code won't run? could you tell what error you get?

Comment: Hey, thanks again. Here is the error:

> class.plot + sex.plot
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> 
> plot_layout(ncol = 2)
$ncol
[1] 2

$nrow
NULL

$byrow
NULL

$widths
NULL

$heights
NULL

$guides
NULL

$tag_level
NULL

$design
NULL

attr(,"class")
[1] "plot_layout"

Comment: Have you the package patchwork installed? It may be the issue here, use "install.package("patchwork")" to do so. + I edited the code, the line starting with plot_layout shouldn't be used, sorry

Comment: Yes, I already download it. Do not worry :) I run your new code but still, I am getting this error: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: This comes from class.plot.

Comment: That weird : it works on my side. Could you try it in a new session, just to be sure there is no conflict or anything? I understand that you run line by line and the error occurs on the line starting with "class.plot <-", am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227770/discussion-between-fsrfyama-and-francois51).